# Выборка двух таблиц (JOIN)

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста. Надо  сделать выборку всех людей не старше 18 лет. Из двух столбец с помощью JOIN. Я сделал выборку без JOIN.Вот таблица:[image: Table]

Вот мой запрос:Select * From personal, family Where BirthDate<'01.01.1999'

Comment: А зачем вам объединять эти таблицы. У вас же в первой таблице уже есть все люди. Во второй таблице никакой новой информации, кроме степени родства не содержится. А степень родства вам вроде выбирать не надо.

Comment: И вторая таблица неправильно построена. Если например Сидоров решит поменять фамилию, то вам придется поменять ее в первой таблице и потом искать его во второй. причем во второй вы сможете это делать только по ФИО, а Сидоровых очень много, вы наверняка зацепите еще других ... По хорошему вторая таблица должна состоять всего из 3х полей: PersonId1, PresonId2, Relation. И то, что Сидоров отец для троих других будет зафиксировано такими записями (2,1,отец),(2,3,отец),(2,4,отец).

Comment: В идеале конечно еще "отец" должно быть вынесено в отдельную таблицу "Степени родства", например "отец" будет с id=10, тогда в таблице family записи приобретут вид (2,1,10),(2,3,10),(2,4,10). Это позволит быстро найти всех отцов не заботясь о том, что одного напишут "отец", другого "Отец", а в третей записи вообще "папа" ...

Comment: хотя и этого не достаточно для реальной системы, только для учебного задания. в реальной системе надо на уровне БД исключать ошибки вроде не добавленной записи "брат". по хорошему такая информация вообще избыточна. все братья находятся как люди имеющие хотя бы одного общего родителя. таким образом было бы достаточно хранить только связи родитель-ребенок. И к ним возможно еще некоторые дополнительные, если нужны всякие крестные и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  "FIO","BirthDate" FROM personal WHERE TO_CHAR("BirthDate", 'YYYY')<'1999'
UNION ALL
SELECT  "FIO","BirthDate" FROM family WHERE TO_CHAR("BirthDate", 'YYYY')<'1999'
```